# Need some suggestion on 220 - 3.3 volt 500 mA power supply (Or 12 volts maximum)

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

[image]
I was planning to make some 220-3.3 volts,5 volts & 12 volts power supplies. I tried the configuration above in proteus (0.47uF, 275 volts RMS, Polypropylene film capacitor in series with a small ferrite core transformer). But the output is very low.

[image]
The output can be increased by placing a resistor in parallel. But there will be a heating effect. Plus if there is a 1K resistor in parallel with that tiny capacitor, I guess there is no point in placing that large Polypropylene film capacitor.

Even 1uF multilayer ceramic (650 volts) capacitor makes 1.5-volt peak. **What should I do? Will this configuration work in practice?** I haven't tested practically yet as the products are in shipment from china and it usually takes 15 days. So I am planning to place an order in JLCPCB. So I checked the proteus simulation result.

[image]

Most probably I'll use this bobbin and cores.

Comment: A mains transformer would not be connected like that. Please provide a link to the transformer or at least make and model.

Comment: What is the load L1? Can you explain how you created this design and how you chose the component values?

Comment: I have different types of cores in my home. I do not buy inductors or ferrite core transformer. I keep wires and cores. I just make the turns according to my target inductance and resistor. Currently, I have E and small toroid cores. Large toroids are on shipment. Bobbins are printed on 3D printers to make the air gap lowest as possible.

Comment: Load L1 will be ESP12E module. Which will control a solid-state relay.

Comment: What is L1 **in your simulation**?

Comment: You need transformers with a primary coil that has enough turns on it to present a high impedance at 50Hz.  The little cores and the thick wire won't work - not enough room for the number of turns of thick wire.  What's happening is that your capacitor limits the current to the coil.  That lowers the voltage to the coil.  The step down of the transformer makes the output even lower.  Work with low voltages from a regular transformer before you go connecting those things to an outlet.

Comment: Oh, I thought because of the capacitor, the voltage will be low across the transformer. So, fewer turns might work.